# Where can I change the address that's now on my site?

Tags: html

Here is the code. I just can't seem to figure out how to change the address of this link. Thank you!

```
  <section id="contact" class="map">
  <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
  <br/>
  <small>
    <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A"></a>
  </small>
</section>
```

Comment: What do you mean by changing the link in HTML?

Comment: You will need to add some javascript to build the href string and insert the required address based on user input or whatever.

Comment: You have to change that link in the Google Business Manager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1** (best for SEO etc)

You have to create a new map by logging into [Google Business Manager](https://business.google.com/locations). In the left menu go to "Create a new site" (or "Add a new site"). Follow the instructions.

---

**Solution 2**

Use [Google Maps Platform - Quick Start Build a Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start). Configure your map as you please and then copy/paste your code located at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you for the help!